# WCF service not running on non-dev machine

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, metadata

I've used this MSDN tutorial on how to get WCF working with net.tcp binding using Windows Services as the host:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

I need nettcp because of callbacks, and don't want to use IIS as a host.

This tutorial works 100% on my computer and, i've done a second version using my own project name and methods etc and this also works 100% on my computer - both when run from VS2010 and when I use InstallUtil and run as a service.

I downloaded Juval Lowy's Metadata explorer and run this on my computer and it finds the service. (from `www.idesign.net`)

I can't get this to work on another computer - ie, the production server. I've also tried installing on a spare pc to see if this was a server related issue. Neither of these have VS2010 however, that shouldn't matter because I'm running as a windows service.

I copy the `/bin/Release` folder from my vs2010 project and put this on the other computer in a folder named `myapp`. I run `InstallUtil` on the service exe (just as I did on my computer) and it installs fine. I also change permissions on the folder to give NETWORK SERVICE full rights.

I then start the service in Control Panel, Admin Services, Services. I have logging to a database and I verify that the service process starts. I can't tell if the WCF hosted service starts.

On my computer whenever WCF hosted services start I get a balloon notification and a window I can look at to see the mex address etc. This doesn't happen when I install onto other computer.

I have installed Juval Lowy's metadata explorer on the target machine but it states invalid address using exact same address as I did on my computer (ie references localhost not IP Address).

I figure something is wrong in my methodology to install on other computer.

The relevant code is:

```
if (myServiceHost != null)
            myServiceHost.Close();

myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyAppService));
myServiceHost.Open();
```

and `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="netTCPBehavior" name="MyAppDll.MyAppDll">
      <endpoint 
          address="" 
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="MyAppDll.IMyAppDll">
         <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint 
          address="mex" 
          binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7200/MyAppDll" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </endpoint>
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="netTCPBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: does `Open` throw any exceptions?

Comment: I would try to explicitly specify the full address for both the service endpoint as well as the MEX endpoint - in the `address=` attribute of the `<endpoint>` tag.

Comment: I've wrapped Open in a try/catch and no exception. I'll look into the full address= but another thought.. i'm going to try and deploy the stock standard MS example on the other machine and see if that works

Comment: OK, the stock standard MS example doesn't work on the other server. I'll look into address=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to enable the [Net.TCP Port Sharing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733925.aspx).

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   uses a Windows service called the
>   Net.TCP Port Sharing Service to
>   facilitate the sharing of TCP ports
>   across multiple processes. This
>   service is installed as part of WCF,
>   but the service is not enabled by
>   default as a security precaution and
>   so must be manually enabled prior to
>   first use.

Comment: I'll need to wait another 15 hours or so before I can try this but I think you may be right.

Comment: I've since discovered that my test project wasn't working 100% and have posted another question. However i've marked this as the answer because I didn't have the port sharing turned on

Comment: Thanks hope you get it working. However not sure why you're using installutil to get a test service up and running. Just run service (and clients) in console applications for now and then once it all works there move it to a windows service. Also installutil is a bit rubbish. Use powershell or wix to deploy your windows services.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on powershell/wix - I'll look into that. I was trying to get it all working on my pc before moving to server - and i've fixed that - msdn example was wrong. Should have fully qualified "Service1" to "wcfServiceLibrary.Service1" and all came good.